# PHP: Simple HTML DOM Parser - multiple attributes in find()?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm using Simple HTML DOM Parser but can't figure out how to get elements that have 2 or more matching attributes.

Sadly, to get the first 2 divs, this doesn't work:

```
$html = "<div title='test a' class='a' >test a</div>
         <div title='test b' class='b' >test b</div>
         <div title='test c' class='c' >test c</div>";

$htmldom = str_get_html($html);
$ab = $htmldom->find("div[class=a][class=b]");
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6):

You can find all divs with either class `a` or class `b` by invoking:

```
$ab = $htmldom->find("div[class=a], div[class=b]");
```

For details, [see manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) on "How to find HTML elements -> Advanced".

Comment: This doesn't work for me. find('h2') works, find('title') works, but find('h2, title') returns nothing.