# Use simple dom parser to find an element by a specific attribute?

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I have simple dom parser working, but I can't find any documentation or examples to get an element by a specific value of an attribute.

I have several tables on one page, but only one that has these attributes with these specific values

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#A0A0A0">
```

How can I echo the whole entire html table with these values.

What I have:

```
<?php include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = htmlspecialchars($_GET["newURL"]);
$html = file_get_html ( $url );
echo $url;
foreach ( $html->find ( 'table' ) as $element ) {

    echo $element . PHP_EOL;
    flush ();
}

?>
```

Comment: where is your PHP code (your trial solution)?

Comment: just added it to the post

Comment: You can use method like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11125414/2194052

Comment: see the manual: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm there are good examples to re-use them :)

Comment: I am really curious is there a specific reason you're using simple html dom library over DomDocument which is shipped with most PHP installations by default?

Comment: how would i print the found table. It keeps returning $ab as an array for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you lazy enough to read the [Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/#frag_access_special)

Look that `Magic attributes` section

> ```
> // Example
> $html = str_get_html("<div>foo <b>bar</b></div>"); 
> $e = $html->find("div", 0);
>
> echo $e->tag; // Returns: " div"
> echo $e->outertext; // Returns: " <div>foo <b>bar</b></div>"
> echo $e->innertext; // Returns: " foo <b>bar</b>"
> echo $e->plaintext; // Returns: " foo bar"
> ```

So in your code, you can use `echo $element->outertext;`

Change your code to

```
<?php
  if ( $table = $html->find( "table" ) ) {
    foreach( $table as $element ) {
      echo $element->outertext.PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: I did that but, I get this error "Trying to get property of non-object in"